# How to add Label controls to a specific place in XAML code programmatically?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to add dynamic Label controls to a specific place in XAML code by pressing a button. I have marked its place in XAML code.
My XAML code is:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MReport.TabbedMainPage">
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
    <ContentPage Title="New Report" IconImageSource="NewReport.png" BackgroundImageSource="blue_windows.jpg">
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ScrollView>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <!--Labels should be add here programmatically every time the button clicked-->
                    </StackLayout>
                </ScrollView>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Add New Item" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
            </Grid>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Send Report" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Title="Report History" IconImageSource="History.png" BackgroundImageSource="blue_windows.jpg" />
    <ContentPage Title="Messages" IconImageSource="Message.png" BackgroundImageSource="blue_windows.jpg"/>

</TabbedPage>
```

For testing purpose, I want to use Test01, Test02, Test03, ... as name for labels.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign a name to the layout

```
<StackLayout x:Name="MyStack">
    <!--Labels should be add here programmatically every time the button clicked-->
</StackLayout>
```

then in code

```
MyStack.Children.Add(new Label { ... });
```

Comment: I added the name "MyStack" but I cannot use it in code-behind. That name does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @Alex. Rebuild Solution.